# How do I align font awesome icon in the middle of select element's height?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How do I align font awesome icon in the middle of select element's height?

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle">
    <select size="10"></select>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gq2mfzuk/

Comment: Flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/gq2mfzuk/1/

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/gq2mfzuk/2/

Comment: Why don't you guys submit formal answers? :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Version 1:**
You can easily do this using flexbox with minimum code. Use the following CSS:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Version 2**
Add the following CSS:

```
div {
    display: table;
    position: absolute
}
a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-flexbox solution:

```
div {display: table}
a {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f48zgdpu/

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```